# prepand and replace in one query mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm explaining with an example for getting my solution.
I've a user table having `id, name, image` fields.

Sample record should be,

```
id - 1
name - TestUser
image - temp/testuser.jpg (sometimes no sub-directory 'temp'. ie, image - testuser.jpg)
```

After user registers, I'm moving the image to a new subdirectory.

ie, moving from `temp/testuser.jpg(testuser.jpg)` to `1/testuser.jpg`

So I need to update with the new url.

ie, I need two operations on here. Replace the sub-directory `temp` with `1`, if no sub-directory prepend '1/' to the existing image url.

How can I manage these operations in one query? Kindly help me :)

Comment: can you post some code coz Its not so much clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the following query

```
update users set
image = concat('new_dir/', substring(image from locate('/', image) + 1))
where id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to separate the directory from the filename. You're adding another field, but it makes it easier.

Upon update, you only need to update the directory it resides in.

Otherwise you can do a `substr()` on the whole path and replace everything up to the last slash.